# How to make TypeWriter to write from start after click again

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make my Typewriter animation start on beginning after i click button "developer". Can't make it work.

```
var i = 0;
var txt = "<!--Ahoj--> \n\n<name> Jmenuji se Tomáš Maixner </name>\n\n<description> Jsem front-end developer, grafický designer a web designer, ale umím toho mnohem víc. Mám zkušenosti se správou sociálních sítí, SEO, animací, produkcí i postprodukcí videa, 3D grafikou i fotografováním. </description>";
var speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {
  {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    var char = txt.charAt(i);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += char == '\n' ? '<br>' : char;
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
  }
 }

function clearBox(demo) {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
  let i = 0;
  let char = txt.charAt(i);
}

function unclearBox(demo) {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
  typeWriter();
}
```

```
<h1>Typewriter</h1>

<div class=window>
 <div class="upper-row">
  
  <div id="developer" onclick="typeWriter(), unclearBox(demo)" class="upper-row-box"><span class="developer"><></span>Developer</div>
  <div onclick="clearBox(demo)" class="upper-row-box"><span class="designer">@</span>Designer</div>
  <div  class="upper-row-box noHover"></div>
  <div class="upper-row-box noHover endBox">
    <div class="dot green"></div>
    <div class="dot yellow"></div>
<div class="dot red"></div>
  </div>


 </div>
 <div id="coding-window" class="coding-window">
  <div class="code">
   <p id="demo"></p>
   <p id="demo2"></p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have tried many things but most of them end up deleting my string. I've never been able restart animation from start.